# Vista preliminar en tiempo de diseño de reporte RDLC

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

Estoy diseñando un reporte RDLC con Visual Studio 2013 y tengo la siguiente duda: hay alguna forma de ir viendo los cambios que voy aplicando a mi reporte  (estilo vista previa de Crystal Reports) en tiempo de diseño? O la única forma es ir diseñando y ejecutando la aplicación para ver mi reporte como va quedando?

Answer (score 1):

Diseñando y ejecutando, nada más.

Comment: Que pena =D Gracias por tu pronta respuesta